# Applescript controlling excel broken in yosemite?

Tags: excel, applescript

I have an applescript controlling Microsoft Excel.  I need to talk to System Events to click some dialog buttons.  Now, after upgrading (sic) to Yosemite, the script alternates between two errors (!!):

1. "System Events got an error: Connection is invalid." number -609, with the cursor on "open wbfile"
2. 'The docuement "tst" could not be opened.  System Events cannot open files in the "Microsoft Excel 97-2004 Worksheet format.'  This error is given in a dialog box, after which clicking 'ok' enables the script to finish successfully.

Somehow, opening a workbook inside of 'tell process "Microsoft Excel"' is not working.
I can open the workbook inside of a 'tell application "Microsoft Excel" just fine, but then
I can't press the dialog buttons.

Any help appreciated!!!

```
set wbfile to "/private/tmp/tst.xls"
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    activate
end tell
delay 0.1
tell application "System Events"
    delay 0.1
    tell process "Microsoft Excel"
        delay 0.1
        set foo to open wbfile
        try
            set cancel to button "Cancel" of window 1
            click (cancel)
        end try
        try
            set macros to button "Enable Macros" of window 1
            click macros
        end try
        try
            set links to button "Ignore Links" of window 1
            click links
        end try
    end tell
end tell

set dat to "flflfl"
set output to (dat as string)
return output
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `ignoring application responses` and let Excel open the file without waiting for the application's feedback. The script will immediately move on to the next steps.
After that the System Events can click the buttons:

```
set wbfile to "/private/tmp/tst.xls"
ignoring application responses
    tell application "Microsoft Excel"
        activate
        set foo to open wbfile
    end tell
end ignoring
delay 1
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Microsoft Excel"
        try
            set cancel to button "Cancel" of window 1
            click (cancel)
        end try
        try
            set macros to button "Enable Macros" of window 1
            click macros
        end try
        try
            set links to button "Ignore Links" of window 1
            click links
        end try
    end tell
end tell
```

Greetings, Michael / Hamburg

Comment: Terrific!!  I am happy to learn about 'ignoring application responses'.  Thanks very much!